# Ошибки при компиляции GLI после обновления GLM с версии 0.9.8.5 до 0.9.9.0

Tags: c++, opengl, c++11, gcc

Установил новую версию библиотеки GLM (OpenGL Mathematics, написана на C++) с [официального сайта](https://glm.g-truc.net). Там же доступна другая библиотека, GLI (OpenGL Image, написана на C++11), которую я ранее также установил [отсюда](https://gli.g-truc.net).

GLI, использующая заголовочные файлы GLM, перестала компилироваться после обновления последней с версии 0.9.8.5 до 0.9.9.0. Версия GLI 0.8.2.0. Среда разработки Dev-Cpp, компилятор `gcc`.

Список ошибок компилятора ниже.

> 1)
>   In constructor 'gli::texture::cache::cache(gli::texture::storage_type&, gli::texture::format_type, gli::texture::size_type, gli::texture::size_type, gli::texture::size_type, gli::texture::size_type, gli::texture::size_type, gli::texture::size_type)':
>
> [Error] invalid static_cast from type 'glm::vec<3, int, (glm::qualifier)0u>' to type 'std::size_t {aka long long unsigned int}'
>
> 2)
>   In constructor 'gli::texture3d::texture3d(gli::texture::format_type, const extent_type&, const swizzles_type&)':
>
> [Error] no matching function for call to 'gli::texture::texture(gli::target, gli::texture::format_type&, const extent_type&, int, int, glm::vec<3, int, (glm::qualifier)0u>, const swizzles_type&)'
>
> 3)
>   In constructor 'gli::texture_cube_array::texture_cube_array(gli::texture::format_type, const extent_type&, gli::texture::size_type, const swizzles_type&)':
>
> [Error] no matching function for call to 'gli::texture::texture(gli::target, gli::texture::format_type&, gli::texture::extent_type, gli::texture::size_type&, int, glm::vec<2, int, (glm::qualifier)0u>, const swizzles_type&)'
>
> 4)
>   In instantiation of 'T gli::levels(T) [with T = glm::vec<3, int, (glm::qualifier)0u>]':
>
> [Error] no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'glm::vec<3, int, (glm::qualifier)0u>' and 'std::size_t {aka long long unsigned int}')
>
> 5)
>   In instantiation of 'T gli::levels(T) [with T = glm::vec<1, int, (glm::qualifier)0u>]':
>
> [Error] no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'glm::vec<1, int, (glm::qualifier)0u>' and 'std::size_t {aka long long unsigned int}')
>
> 6)
>   In instantiation of 'T gli::levels(T) [with T = glm::vec<2, int, (glm::qualifier)0u>]':
>
> [Error] no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'glm::vec<2, int, (glm::qualifier)0u>' and 'std::size_t {aka long long unsigned int}')

UPD: Версия GCC - 4.9, проблема не в поддержке GLM данного компилятора, а в том, что совместимость GLI с GLM сломалась из-за обновления, с предыдущей версией всё работало. Не нашёл у них на сайте GLM раздела с вопросами или технической поддержки, а GLI не обновлялась с 2016 года, даже не знаю, куда написать о проблеме.

Comment: А может так оказаться, что Ваш GCC из Dev-Cpp больше не поддерживается этими библиотеками? Он у Вас версии 4.7 или новее (как того хочет новая версия GLM)? Или более древний?

Comment: @Игорь GLI 0.8.2 [не совместима](https://github.com/g-truc/gli/releases) с GLM 0.9.9. В 0.9.9 помимо перехода на C++11, изменился список параметров шаблона векторов.